# Event not triggered in dynamically generated buttons

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have generated buttons dynamically but press event is not being triggered.

I also tried giving each press event same function name but it doesn't work.

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  var pr = "onPress" + i;
  var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Save",
    press: pr
  });
  // ...
}
```

Following error is shown in console after I click the button:

> EventProvider-dbg.js:228 Uncaught TypeError: I.fFunction.call is not a function
>       at f.b.fireEvent (EventProvider-dbg.js:228)
>       at f.b.fireEvent (Element-dbg.js:557)
>       at f.firePress (ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:764)
>       at f.d.ontap (Button-dbg.js:300)
>       at f.b._handleEvent (Element-dbg.js:259)
>       at constructor.U._handleEvent (UIArea-dbg.js:921)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-dbg.js:4737)
>       at g (jquery-mobile-custom-dbg.js:1881)
>       at HTMLDivElement.r (jquery-mobile-custom-dbg.js:2000)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-dbg.js:4737)

Comment: `press` awaits a function (or an array with data, function, and listener). You're assigning strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`press` should be a `function`, try something like this:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Save",
    press: () => {
      console.log("onPress" + i);
    }
  });
  // ...
}
```

I also declared `i` with the `let` keyword as the callback is going to be executed async